# How to configure NICs for LAN & WAN for Windows Server 2012 Essentials?

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v

I’m familiar with having 2 NICs on an SBS2003 server, where one is getting its IP from the internet router’s DHCP e.g. 192.168.1.2 for the WAN and the other is static e.g. 192.168.18.2 for the LAN.
I am new to Server 2012 R2. I have 2 physical NICs in the Hyper-V host running a Server 2012 R2 guest with the Server Essentials Experience role installed, but not yet configured. I have searched over several days for answers to this but suspect I’m using the wrong terms.
Is it good practice to split the NIC roles as above between WAN and LAN?
How do I configure the correct setup of these NICs in the Hyper-V host and the Server 2012 R2 guest?
Does such configuration provide the same or better protection of the client VMs as I’m familiar with, where the client PC VMs all have the SBS2003 server’s LAN NIC as their gateway and are thus protected by the server’s ISA firewall?
Any advice or link to what I’ve clearly missed so far in all my reading, will be much appreciated.

I have since found the following links and am still absorbing them, but was hoping to find a simple guide to secure setup of a small LAN where clients PCs access the WAN through a Server 2012.
http://www.falconitservices.com/support/KB/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=77
http://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2009/08/17/multihomed-dcs-with-dns-rras-and-or-pppoe-adapters/

Comment: I don't think what you are doing or trying to do is a reasonable business practice. I assume you want to use the free Hyper-V license bundled to your Server 2012 license. If so, you are not allowed to install any other role on the physical machine, than the Hyper-V role. Server 2012 Essentials is not meant to be installed with two NICs (read documentation). If you virtualise it, give it one virtual network adapter and use the wizards, as it is intended by Microsoft.

Comment: Only 1 nic is needed but you can certainly have more than 1

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was looking for. It confirms only 1 NIC needed. "Secure remote access in small and midsize businesses" http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn629457.aspx